# Redshift joins with unused tables performance

Tags: join, view, amazon-redshift, query-performance

If one has a view over two tables in Redshift - using a left join, then makes a query selecting columns only from the left table from this view - Will it be optimized so that the join will be ignored, and the other table not read at all?

Comment: Check the execution plan: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ANALYZE.html

Comment: please change the title and replace "postgresql" with "redshift" as they are not the same.

Comment: how can it ignore table 2? it needs to perform the join to see how many output rows will be produced (e.g. one to many or 1 to none)

Comment: I updated the title, and also the question - Jon, I meant for the join is a left join, so that way whatever is on table 2 doesn't really matter

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I ran analyze and looked into `stl_analyze`, but I'm not sure how to figure out the answer from there.

Comment: yes it does matter what is on table 2! because if you left join "1 to n" then you get n results, not 1

Comment: @JonScott I understand now, I see my question was naive. I meant for a "1 to 1" join, but I guess there's no way for the engine to realize that. Thank you for your help.